# QUE JS ME CREE DIVS EN FUNCION AL PARAMETRO RECIBIDO POR PY

Tags: javascript, html, python, conflictos

estoy creando un Flipbook. Para lograrlo, creè un codigo py que convierte todos los archivos en formato pdf a jpg y con JS a traves del DOM quiero que se reproduzcan las imagenes de manera automatica en el flipbook. Lo que no estoy logrando que suceda, es que se me generen tantos divs como imagenes tenga mi pdf, solo puedo cargarlas una por una en el HTML. Adjunto mi codigo a ver si alguien puede ayudarme:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = 1050, user-scalable = no" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="files/extras/jquery.min.1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="files/extras/modernizr.2.5.3.min.js"></script>
        <title>Flipbook</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flipbook-viewport">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="flipbook">
                <div style="background-image:url(files/pages/1.jpg)"></div>
                <div style="background-image:url(files/pages/2.jpg)"></div>
                <div style="background-image:url(files/pages/3.jpg)"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    function loadApp() {
    
        // Create the flipbook
    
        $('.flipbook').turn({
                // Width
    
                width:922,
                
                // Height
    
                height:600,
    
                // Elevation
    
                elevation: 50,
                
                // Enable gradients
    
                gradients: true,
                
                // Auto center this flipbook
    
                autoCenter: true
    
        });
    }
    
    // Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform
    
    yepnope({
        test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
        yep: ['files/lib/turn.js'],
        nope: ['files/lib/turn.html4.min.js'],
        both: ['files/css/basic.css'],
        complete: loadApp
    });
    
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
/*
 * Basic sample
*/

function addPage(page, book) {

    var id, pages = book.turn('pages');

    // Create a new element for this page
    // var element = $('<div />', {});

    var element = $(contador);


    // Add the page to the flipbook
    if (book.turn('addPage', element, page)) {

        // Add the initial HTML
        // It will contain a loader indicator and a gradient
        element.html('<div class="gradient"></div><div class="loader"></div>');

        // Load the page
        loadPage(page, element);
    }

}

function loadPage(page, pageElement) {

    // Create an image element

    var img = $('<img />');

    img.mousedown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    img.load(function() {
        
        // Set the size
        $(this).css({width: '100%', height: '100%'});

        // Add the image to the page after loaded

        $(this).appendTo(pageElement);

        // Remove the loader indicator
        
        pageElement.find('.loader').remove();
    });

    // Load the page

    img.attr('src', 'pages/' +  page + '.jpg');

}


function loadLargePage(page, pageElement) {
    
    var img = $('<img />');

    img.load(function() {

        var prevImg = pageElement.find('img');
        $(this).css({width: '100%', height: '100%'});
        $(this).appendTo(pageElement);
        prevImg.remove();
        
    });

    // Loadnew page
    
    img.attr('src', 'pages/' +  page + '-large.jpg');
}


function loadSmallPage(page, pageElement) {
    
    var img = pageElement.find('img');

    img.css({width: '100%', height: '100%'});

    img.unbind('load');
    // Loadnew page

    img.attr('src', 'pages/' +  page + '.jpg');
}



// http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128488
function isChrome() {

    return navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')!=-1;

}
```

** PY **

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes



images = convert_from_path('Reglas.pdf',size=(500,500), output_folder='./')

for i in range(len(images)):
     images[i].save(f"{i+1}.jpg")
```

Hola, estoy creando un Flipbook. Para lograrlo, creè un codigo py que convierte todos los archivos en formato pdf a jpg y con JS a traves del DOM quiero que se reproduzcan las imagenes de manera automatica en el flipbook. Lo que no estoy logrando que suceda, es que se me generen tantos divs como imagenes tenga mi pdf, solo puedo cargarlas una por una en el HTML. Adjunto mi codigo a ver si alguien puede ayudarme: